# fetching height with jquery and using it to move another element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a drop-down menu which "takes the menu button with it" as it drops down from outside the viewport so that the menu button will be positioned after the menu. The position value of the menu button is fixed.

I'm using this code to try and do it:

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("nav").slideToggle();
    var h = $("nav").height;
    console.log(h);
    $(this).css("top", h)
});
```

And this is what "console.log(h)" returns:

function (e,f){var g=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof e),h=c||(e===!0||f===!0?"margin":"border");return T(this,function(b,c,e){var f;return r.isWindow(b)?0===d.indexOf("outer")?b["inner"+a]:b.document.…

What soes it mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis, because of which function is not getting executed and function definition is getting assigned to variable h.

Please change code like below.

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
  $("nav").slideToggle();
  var h = $("nav").height();
  $(this).css("top", h);
});
```

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: You can use this site https://jsfiddle.net/ or you can simply add your code in question.
you are getting 0, may be coz nav is getting collapsed on toggle.